# Simple Chat Client-Server Encryption

Tags: c#, encryption, client, client-server, aes

I wanted to make a chat client server, very simple, but at the same time very safe, using AES-256bit. I have thought so, tell me if I'm wrong, of course.
The various client enter in a  "secure" textbox the passwords (which must be the same everywhere) and in the sending functions (of the client program), clients encrypt messages that I put in another ordinary textbox, using the password and send them to the server; the receiving function always decrypts always using the same key. The server should instead do nothing at the encryption level. 
I tried, but I do not know if it doesn't work because of at the code level. 
Here's how I modified both the sending and receiving functions on the client: send function

```
// send the message to the server
private void SendMessage()
{
    if (txtMessage.Lines.Length >= 1)
    {
        byte[] passwordBytes = GetPasswordBytes();
        encrypted_message = AES.Encrypt(txtMessage.Text, passwordBytes);
        swSender.WriteLine(encrypted_message);
        swSender.Flush();
        txtMessage.Lines = null;
    }
    txtMessage.Text = "";
}
```

receiving function:

```
private void ReceiveMessages()
{
    // Receive the response from the server
    srReceiver = new StreamReader(tcpServer.GetStream());
    // If the first character of the response is 1, connection was successful
    string ConResponse = srReceiver.ReadLine();
    // If the first character is a 1, connection was successful
    if (ConResponse[0] == '1')
    {
        // Update the form to tell it we are now connected
        this.Invoke(new UpdateLogCallback(this.UpdateLog), new object[] { "Connessione avvenuta con successo!" });
    }
    else // If the first character is not a 1 (probably a 0), the connection was unsuccessful
    {
        string Reason = "Non connesso: ";
        // Extract the reason out of the response message. The reason starts at the 3rd character
        Reason += ConResponse.Substring(2, ConResponse.Length - 2);
        // Update the form with the reason why we couldn't connect
        this.Invoke(new CloseConnectionCallback(this.CloseConnection), new object[] { Reason });
        // Exit the method
        return;
    }
    // While we are successfully connected, read incoming lines from the server
    while (Connected == true)
    {
            try
            {
                // Show the messages decrypted in the log TextBox
                this.Invoke(new UpdateLogCallback(this.MessageUpdateLog), new object[] { srReceiver.ReadLine() });

            }
            catch
            {
                try
                {
                this.Invoke(new UpdateLogCallback(this.UpdateLog), new object[] { srReceiver.ReadLine() });
                }
                catch { }
            }
    }
}

// This method is called from a different thread in order to update the log TextBox
private void UpdateLog(string strMessage)
{
    txtLog.AppendText(strMessage + "\r\n");
}

//Decrypt the messages incoming from the other client
private void MessageUpdateLog(string strMessage_de)
{
    byte[] passwordBytes = GetPasswordBytes();
    strMessage_de = AES.Decrypt(strMessage_de, passwordBytes);
    // Append text also scrolls the TextBox to the bottom each time
    txtLog.AppendText(strMessage_de + "\r\n");
}
```

not to make the job hard, I thought of exchange encryption passwords (keys) via voice, since it would be a chat room for personal use.

Comment: Is there a question in here?

Comment: yes: because this doesn't work. The program doesn't work at logic level or at code level?